# Save row multi-diagram to PDF in R without 1:1 ratio

Tags: r, plot

I am trying to generate a PDF image in R of three plots arranged in a row grid. This is what I tried:

```
pdf("fig.pdf")
par(mfrow=c(1,3))
plot(rnorm(100), rnorm(100), xlab="Something on X", ylab="Some on Y", main="This is it 1")
plot(rnorm(100), rnorm(100), xlab="Something on X", ylab="Some on Y", main="This is it 2")
plot(rnorm(100), rnorm(100), xlab="Something on X", ylab="Some on Y", main="This is it 3")
dev.off()
```

But it produces:

[image]

While I want each diagram to be square and the final image not to have a 1:1 ratio:

[image]

---

#### Attempts

I have tried:

```
pdf("fig.pdf", width = 3, height = 1)
```

But that generated errors when plotting each single diagram, complaining the size was not enough:

> Error in plot.new() : figure margins too large

If I try:

```
par(mfrow=c(1,3), pty='s')
```

Then:

[image]

How can I achieve this (possibly without using external libraries, but simple basic default R packages)?

Comment: add `par(mfrow=c(1,3), pty='s')` after the `pdf` call in your first attempt.

Comment: @user20650: Does not work :( It generates a square PDF. In the end each single plot is square, but a lot of blank space up and down is left

Comment: @user20650: You can see the edited question

Comment: ah okay, maybe scale the inputs `pdf("fig.pdf", width=7, height=7/3)` with the `par` calls?

Comment: @user20650: Yes... please post an answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I used

```
pdf("fig.pdf", width=6, height=2.4)
par(mfrow=c(1,3))
plot(rnorm(100), rnorm(100), xlab="Something on X", ylab="Some on Y", main="This is it 1")
plot(rnorm(100), rnorm(100), xlab="Something on X", ylab="Some on Y", main="This is it 2")
plot(rnorm(100), rnorm(100), xlab="Something on X", ylab="Some on Y", main="This is it 3")
dev.off()
```

and got this:

[image: Three square plots]

Comment: Yes that does the trick. So I can specify a width and then use `width/n` to avoid a dependency on the size!

Comment: Yes,  but the labels on the top and bottom take up more space than the labels on the sides, so you may need a height slightly bigger than width/n

Comment: @G5W ; I think you can use `width/n` if you set the plot region to square, to save manually finding a width